# Xgboost random seed setting does not ensures reproduce-ability

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

In spite of setting a value for `random_state` and/or `seed` parameter, the performance is not reproducible in [Xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html) Sklearn API wrapper

Here is the code

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

(X_train,y_train),(X_eval,y_eval) = pickle.load(open('xxxx.pkl',"rb"))

hyperparams = {'eval_metric': 'auc', 'colsample_bylevel': 0.7, 'learning_rate': 0.125,  'random_state': 0}
GBM = XGBClassifier(**hyperparams)
GBM.fit(X_train,y_train,eval_metric="auc",verbose = True,eval_set=[(X_eval,y_eval)],early_stopping_rounds=2)

print(roc_auc_score(y_eval, GBM.predict_proba(X_eval)[:,1]))
```

Each time, when I run the above snippet the concordance value differs.

```
78.9451246
79.001542
```

Some references 
[issues](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3921)