# How are the test scores in cv_results_ and best_score_ calculated in scikit-optimize?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, xgboost, scikit-optimize

I'm using `BayesSearchCV` from `scikit-optimize` to optimise an `XGBoost` model to fit some data I have. While the model fits fine, I am puzzled by the scores provided in the diagnostic information and am unable to replicate them.

Here's an example script using the Boston house prices dataset to illustrate my point:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor

from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from skopt.space import Real, Categorical, Integer
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, train_test_split 

boston = load_boston()

# Dataset info:
print(boston.keys())
print(boston.data.shape)
print(boston.feature_names)
print(boston.DESCR)

# Put data into dataframe and label column headers:

data = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)
data.columns = boston.feature_names

# Add target variable to dataframe

data['PRICE'] = boston.target

# Split into X and y

X, y = data.iloc[:, :-1],data.iloc[:,-1]

# Split into training and validation datasets 

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle = True) 

# For cross-validation, split training data into 5 folds

xgb_kfold = KFold(n_splits = 5,random_state = 42)

# Run fit

xgb_params = {'n_estimators': Integer(10, 3000, 'uniform'),
               'max_depth': Integer(2, 100, 'uniform'),
               'subsample': Real(0.25, 1.0, 'uniform'),
               'learning_rate': Real(0.0001, 0.5, 'uniform'),
               'gamma': Real(0.0001, 1.0, 'uniform'),
               'colsample_bytree': Real(0.0001, 1.0, 'uniform'),
               'colsample_bylevel': Real(0.0001, 1.0, 'uniform'),
               'colsample_bynode': Real(0.0001, 1.0, 'uniform'),
               'min_child_weight': Real(1, 6, 'uniform')}

xgb_fit_params = {'early_stopping_rounds': 15, 'eval_metric': 'mae', 'eval_set': [[X_val, y_val]]}

xgb_pipe = XGBRegressor(random_state = 42,  objective='reg:squarederror', n_jobs = 10)

xgb_cv = BayesSearchCV(xgb_pipe, xgb_params, cv = xgb_kfold, n_iter = 5, n_jobs = 1, random_state = 42, verbose = 4, scoring = None, fit_params = xgb_fit_params)

xgb_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

After running this,  `xgb_cv.best_score_` is 0.816, and `xgb_cv.best_index_` is 3. Looking at xgb_cv.cv_results_, I want to find the best scores for each fold:

```
print(xgb_cv.cv_results_['split0_test_score'][xgb_cv.best_index_], xgb_cv.cv_results_['split1_test_score'][xgb_cv.best_index_], xgb_cv.cv_results_['split2_test_score'][xgb_cv.best_index_], xgb_cv.cv_results_['split3_test_score'][xgb_cv.best_index_], xgb_cv.cv_results_['split4_test_score'][xgb_cv.best_index_])
```

Which gives:

```
0.8023562337946979,
 0.8337404778903412,
 0.861370681263761,
 0.8749312273014963,
 0.7058815015739375
```

I'm not sure what's being calculated here, because `scoring` is set to `None` in my code. XGBoost's documentation isn't much help, but according to `xgb_cv.best_estimator_.score?` it's supposed to be the R2 of the predicted values. Anyway, I'm unable to obtain these values when I manually try calculating the score for each fold of the data used in the fit:

```
# First, need to get the actual indices of the data from each fold:

kfold_indexes = {}
kfold_cnt = 0

for train_index, test_index in xgb_kfold.split(X_train):
    kfold_indexes[kfold_cnt] = {'train': train_index, 'test': test_index}
    kfold_cnt = kfold_cnt+1

# Next, calculate the score for each fold   
for p in range(5): print(xgb_cv.best_estimator_.score(X_train.iloc[kfold_indexes[p]['test']], y_train.iloc[kfold_indexes[p]['test']]))
```

Which gives me the following:

```
0.9954929618573786
0.994844803666101
0.9963108152027245
0.9962274544089832
0.9931314653538819
```

How is BayesSearchCV calculating the scores for each fold, and why can't I replicate them using the `score` function? I would be most grateful for any assistance with this issue.

(Also, manually calculating the mean of these scores gives: 0.8156560..., while `xgb_cv.best_score_` gives: 0.8159277... Not sure why there's a precision difference here.)

Comment: Your first set of scores are _test_ fold scores, while the second set are _train_ fold scores.

Comment: @BenReiniger I try using the test indices, but I still don't get the right values: ```for p in range(5): print(xgb_cv.best_estimator_.score(X_train.iloc[kfold_indexes[p]['test']], y_train.iloc[kfold_indexes[p]['test']]))``` gives: 0.9954929618573786, 0.994844803666101, 0.9963108152027245, 0.9962274544089832, 0.9931314653538819

Comment: @BenReiniger: I've changed the predicted scores following your advice. What else might be wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`best_estimator_` is the refitted estimator, fitted on the entire training set after choosing the hyperparameters; so scoring it on any portion of the training set will be optimistically biased.  To reproduce `cv_results_`, you would need to refit estimators to each training fold and `score` the corresponding test fold.

---

Beyond that, there does appear to be more randomness not covered by the XGBoost `random_state`.  There is another parameter `seed`; setting that produces consistent results for me.  (There are some older posts here ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53084599/10495893)) reporting similar issues even with `seed` set, but perhaps those have been resolved by newer versions of xgb.)

Comment: If this is the case, then should passing ```X_train``` to ```score``` give the same value as ```best_score_```? Because I tried doing that and the values are still markedly different.

Comment: No.  `best_score_` is the largest `mean_test_score`, which is based on out-of-fold scores; whereas `xgb_cv.score` is shorthand for `xgb_cv.best_estimator_.score`, which is  the scoring method of the retrained model, and so "cheating".

Comment: Having refitted a new XGBoost model using the same parameters as the best_estimator_ I now get much closer values (Original CV scores: ```0.80235623, 0.83374048, 0.86137068, 0.87493123, 0.7058815```
My emulation attempt: ```0.81142551, 0.82771065, 0.87877982, 0.88612015, 0.70819454```). But they're still not exact. Why would there still be a difference?

Comment: Hm.  You've set random states in all of xgboost, kfold, and bayessearch, so that should be fine.  Same dataset, I assume.  I would try with sklearn's GBM and random search, to isolate whether the effect is due to xgboost or skopt.

Comment: I've tried replacing BayesSearchCV with sklearn's RandomizedSearchCV, and for 5 folds I get the same values. However, for 2 folds the score for the 2nd fold is markedly different. Would my problem therefore be a consequence of XGBoost instead of RandomizedSearchCV or BayesSearchCV? Why would supplying the exact same parameters and data cause two different scores?

Comment: I got around to testing myself, and it does seem like an xgboost issue. I've added to the answer.